# Mediaplayer.play method taking time

Tags: windows-phone-7

We are developing a XNA game with high interactivity. The game includes some background music.

We are trying to play the background music through the MEdiaplayer.play method.  But this seems to block the smooth gameplay for a while. How can this be overcome?

Had tried using the soundeffect instance for this initially  and it worked fine. But that approach doesn't seem to go well with the certification requirements.      Pls help

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal for large music files. You could however try to put

```
IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

after

```
TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(???);
```

I have found that that makes a smoother gamepay. At least back in 7.0 - but I still use it.

I of course assume that you use elapsed time for all animations.